# Why is my patch failing a test?

Tags: testing, version-control

When a patch fails testing because it doesn't apply, and the error reads "Ensure the patch applies to the tip of the chosen code-base." what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

Basically your patch have to be applyable with the command

```
patch -p1 < $filename.patch
```

http://drupal.org/node/707484 is a pretty good tutorial how to create patches so the testbot can use it.

Comment: It is, or at least it was.

Comment: Don't forget that HEAD is moving fast these days.